# Exclude-File in Solaris 8 doesn't work

Tags: shell, unix, backup, solaris, tar

I've to tar the whole Solaris System. Therefore I wrote a script. When I run this script as root everything works fine! When I'm running the same script out of cron I get an

> tar: --exclude-from=: No such file or directory

or

> tar: can't change directories to --exclude-from=/home/BACKUP: No such file or directory

What I'm doing is the following:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash


#########################################################################
# Author:               Marcus Gehring                                  #
#########################################################################
#tar -cvpf /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz --exclude-from=/home/BACKUP/$(uname -n).exclude / >> /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_BACKUP.log 2>&1
tar -cvpf /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz --exclude-from= "/home/BACKUP/$(uname -n).exclude" / >> /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_BACKUP.log 2>&1
```

But both doesn't work. I've also tested the following:

```
tar -cvpf /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz -X "/home/BACKUP/$(uname -n).exclude" / >> /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_BACKUP.log 2>&1
```

Exclude file is as follows:

```
/home*
/usr/local/var/httpd*
/usr/local/var/openldap-data*
```

I've also tried another part of the exclude file if this is the reason. So my second exclude file content was:

```
/home
/usr/local/var/httpd
/usr/local/var/openldap-data
```

Anyone an Idea whats going wrong?
Just for clarification:
exclude, log and archive is in one directory.

Tar-Version:

> tar (GNU tar) 1.13.25
>
> Copyright ? 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
>
> You may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public
>
> License; see the file named COPYING for details. Written by John
>
> Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.

Regards

Marcus

UPDATE 1:

Hi Mark, thanks for your support :) But this are only the commands copied of my backup_script.sh ;) In the Crontab the call is:

```
# Backup on UNIX since 08162017 
01 5 * * * /home/BACKUP/backup_script.sh
```

UPDATE2:

During the day, I've tested several other commands in the script:

```
tar -cvpf /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz --exclude-from=/home/BACKUP/$(uname -n).exclude / >> /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_BACKUP.log 2>&1
tar -cvpf /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz --exclude-from= "/home/BACKUP/$(uname -n).exclude" / >> /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_BACKUP.log 2>&1
tar -cvpf /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz -X '/home/BACKUP/$(uname -n).exclude' / >> /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_BACKUP.log 2>&1
tar -cvpf /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz -X "/home/BACKUP/$(uname -n).exclude" / >> /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_BACKUP.log 2>&1
tar -cvpf /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz "/home/BACKUP/$(uname -n).exclude" / >> /home/BACKUP/$(uname -n)_BACKUP.log 2>&1
```

It all ends in the same result. Excluded files not excluded and on the -X path I got "tar: -X: No such file or directory" same as on "--exclude-from" before.

Comment: You may need to escape `%` signs by preceding with backslash like this `\%` inside `crontab`.

Comment: Updated the Description

Comment: Click `edit` under your question and update it - code is impossible to read in comments...

Comment: You need to show both the `crontab` line and also the salient parts of any scripts that `cron` executes.

Comment: Updated as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was difference between used tar when starting from crontab and as user tar.

simply add `which tar` to your script and compare the output with `which tar` from the console to see the difference.